# Is there a way to have a stop recursion in prolog after a certain number of iterations?

Tags: prolog

This the code I have written,

```
passesBatonTo(bob, doug).
passesBatonTo(doug, steve).
passesBatonTo(steve, sam).
passesBatonTo(sam, bob).

getRelayTeam(X):-
    passesBatonTo(X, Y),
    write(Y), nl,
    getRelayTeam(Y).
```

I want the code give the full relay team but the code goes into infinite loop.

Eg: getRelayTeam(bob) should give bob, doug, steve, sam

or

getRelayTeam(steve) should give steve, sam, bob, doug

Answer (score 0):

You could try this trick, with a countdown value:

```
passesBatonTo(bob, doug).
passesBatonTo(doug, steve).
passesBatonTo(steve, sam).
passesBatonTo(sam, bob).

% getRelayTeam(X,RelaysLeft)

getRelayTeam(X,0) :- 
   !, % tell Prolog there is no point in trying the next clause if this head matched
   format("No more relays for you, ~q is the last carrier!\n",[X]).

getRelayTeam(X,RelaysLeft) :-
    RelaysLeft > 0, % make clear we want RelaysLeft > 0 (even though we use ! above)
    passesBatonTo(X, Y),
    format("Passed baton from ~q to ~q\n",[X,Y]),
    succ(RelaysLeftNow,RelaysLeft),
    getRelayTeam(Y,RelaysLeftNow).
```

And so:

```
?- getRelayTeam(bob,4).
Passed baton from bob to doug
Passed baton from doug to steve
Passed baton from steve to sam
Passed baton from sam to bob
No more relays for you, bob is the last carrier!
true.
```